# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on WiX installer build when PermissionEx is used

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, installation, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to set folder permissions on creation. I want to modify permissions, instead of overwriting current, so I have used `<PermissionEx/>` tag from WiXUtilExtension instead of classic `<Permission/>` tag. I have added reference to WixUtilExtension.dll v4.0.0.0. WiX version is v4.0.4305.0. In WiX header I have added namespace `<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">`. When I try to set permission like

```
<Component Id="CreateFolder" Directory="DIRECTORYID" Guid="MY_GUID">
    <CreateFolder>
      <Permission User="[LogonUser]" GenericAll="yes"/>
    </CreateFolder> 
</Component>
```

installer build succesfully.
However, when I use

```
<Component Id="CreateFolder" Directory="DIRECTORYID" Guid="MY_GUID">
    <CreateFolder>
       <util:PermissionEx User="[LogonUser]" GenericAll="yes"/>
    </CreateFolder> 
</Component>
```

installer build stops with exception [image: Visual Studio crash]

and Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition crashes completely.
Directory is created like:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" >
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" >
          <Directory Id="DIRECTORYID" Name="TestDir"/>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Do you have any clues, if I am something doing wrong, or it is bug in newest WiX build?